# Logout button in Django Mezzanine

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, mezzanine

I am doing a project with Python and Django Mezzanine. I have a login menu in localhost/accounts. But I do not have a logout menu, once I'm log...

Somebody know how to do, because, I really need this for continue
Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem and your current effort?

Comment: Here are some more questions. What is "login menu"? Is it for admin page or front end login? Have you written any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into settings.py and look at the installed apps listing. Uncomment `'mezzanine.accounts'`. This can take care of all your login stuff for you. Check out [the mezzanine docs](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/user-accounts.html) for details.

Comment: Excuse for the late (I'm french), 'mezzanine.accounts' is activated but I don't know how to do the menu even I look the doc... I think, I'm really bad